# Jetpack Compose - How to cut the word before moving to a new line?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

In Jetpack Compose, I created the following Text component:

```
Text(
    text = "aa bb cc ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
    maxLines = 2,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    modifier = Modifier.weight(0.55f)
)
```

Here is what I see on my screen:

```
aa bb cc 
ddddddddddddddddd...
```

How can I achieve this result:

```
aa bb cc ddddddddd
ddddddddddddddd...
```

My main goal is to be able to cut a word in the middle and make it fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following to see if it works as expected:

```
Text(
    text = "aa bb cc ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph),
    maxLines = 2,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    modifier = Modifier.weight(0.55f)
)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Please try to add lineBreak to have the result as you expected:

```
Text(
        text = "aa bb cc ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
        maxLines = 2,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Visible,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(0.55f),
        style = TextStyle(lineBreak = LineBreak.Paragraph)
)
```